Laravel форматирование данных
Всем привет. Чутка запутался. Как приводить к одному формату данных
мне пришлось вынести в сервис вот такой запрос
class SupportService
{
    public function findUserTicket(int $userId): LengthAwarePaginator
    {
        return Support::where('user_id', $userId)
            ->select('support_id', 'is_closed', 'is_resolved', 'status', 'summary', 'updated_at')
            ->first();
    }
}

возникла необходимость вызвать этот метод в другом сервисе, чтобы обработать данные
но в новом сервисе у меня все переменные в CamelCase а findUserTickets возвращает в snake_case и получается путаница при работе с переменными
Как вы это решаете? Буду признателен и спасибо

"но в новом сервисе у меня все переменные в CamelCase а findUserTickets возвращает в snake_case" -- свойства модели в Laravel всегда snake case, это общепринятая практика или о чем Вы конкретно? Cоглашения сообщества об именовании

получается, что такая запись $ticket = $this->userService->findById(34); $ticketName = $ticket->ticket_name .' - '.$ticket->ticket_id;  return ['ticketName' => $ticketName] является нормальной практикой?

Да, вполне. Можете поместить это в отдельный метод модели public function getTicketNameAttribute() { return $tihis->ticket_name . ' - ' . $this->ticket_id; } и получить данный атрибут таким образом $ticket->ticket_name
